# pip uninstall package AND unique dependencies

Tags: python, pip

How does one cleanly uninstall a pip installed package and all dependencies used by package only (i.e. not shared with other packages)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

pip does not natively support removing unused dependencies. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-virtualenv/JqIbyUDy2-E/discussion) is a related discussion thread by the pip developers.

There are several options you can consider:

1. There is a package [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove), but it is no longer maintained, so you cannot be sure if it works and should use it with caution.
2. There is another package [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) which shows you the dependency tree of installed packages. See the dependency tree yourself and decide what is safe to be deleted.
3. What I do is to work on virtual environments and write a `requirements.txt` for each environment. When I want to remove a package, I take it away from `requirements.txt`, and just completely delete the virtual environment. Then I re-create the environment with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: `pipdeptree` looks the most interesting of the three choices. I will investigate further. Thank you.

Comment: In general: Using virtualenvs and recreating them from scratch every few weeks isn't a bad idea either.
I would just recommend to keep the lastest working output of `pip freeze` in case a project breaks after updating a virtualenv

Comment: honestly dependency management sucks with python. still yet to find a legit dependency manager