# how to uninstall packages installed with pip3 and it's dependencies?

Tags: pip, centos, airflow

I was installing apache-airflow in my centOS 8. Only pip3 works in my environment. I did something with the environment variable which created two config files for airflow. I am not able to find another config file to delete it. So, I was trying to uninstall airflow. I used

```
pip3 uninstall apache-airflow
```

It removed the package but still, the other dependent files that were installed are there. I googled and found `pip-autoremove` but it doesn't work for pip3.

I am trying to find a way to clean install airflow again by removing all the old files, dependent packages. Is there a way to use autoremove in pip3 or are there any other alternatives for my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip uninstall package AND unique dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470523/pip-uninstall-package-and-unique-dependencies)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall+dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you make a new Virtual Environment and then install your package inside it.

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
source <venv>/bin/activate.csh
pip3 install apache-airflow
pip3 freeze > dependencies.txt
```

Then make a pip freeze and now you can delete all installed packages (which are apache-airflow and its dependencies) in you working environment. So you can go to your working environment and just delete them:

```
pip3 uninstall -r <path>/dependencies.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the files under $AIRFLOW_HOME (default path: `~/airflow`). Airflow will look for config file at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg`. So reinstall airflow, set `$AIRFLOW_HOME` to the place where you want to have all your config files and DAGs as mentioned in https://airflow.apache.org/start.html.